# Why am I seeing 'true' next to these timestamps?

Tags: timestamp

Click on the Beers tab on this page: http://beernews.org/brewery/sierra-nevada-brewing/

UPDATE: [Here is the Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dRfLY1et) for Excerpt.php. Note that excerpt.php is called in other places on the site (like the home page and the first tab on the link above and no 'true' appears.)

Here's the code:

```
<div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="tabs-2">

   <?php 

    $post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $post_ID = $post_obj->ID;
    $post_title = $post_obj->post_title;
    $brewery_slug = $post_obj->post_name;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'beer',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brewery',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $brewery_slug
            )
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'excerpt', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php else :?>

                <div style="display:block;margin-top:50px;">

                    <p><?php echo 'Click above to zoom in. Area is still in development so no posts yet. Try the specs tab.';?></p>

                </div>

<?php endif;

// Prevent weirdness
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Can we see the template for `excerpt.php`?

Comment: We need to see the template file `excerpt.php`, which you are calling with get_template_part, because that `entry-meta` div is rendered from that file.

Comment: Updated the post. Here's the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/dRfLY1et

I grabbed it from local (so just replace localhost/wordpress with beernews.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am referenceing http://pastebin.com/dRfLY1et

In line 74 either delete `echo 'true';` or comment it out. That should keep it from displaying.

Comment: ah, poor form on my part to not even look at excerpt.php though it was after midnight!